# TSQL constrain so that there can not be to rows with same column A but different column B values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints

Need constrain that will refuse insert/update if there is already some row with same value in column `A` but different value in `B`.

So:

```
Insert TableName(A, B) Values(x, y)
Insert TableName(A, B) Values(x, y)
Insert TableName(A, B) Values(x, z)
```

Will fail on the **third** inser as y =/=z. Or even on the first insert if there was already row (x, w) in the table.

On the other hand those inserts are valid:

```
Insert TableName(A, B) Values(c, y)
Insert TableName(A, B) Values(d, y)
```

Last remark. Data won't be normalized. Non normalized form is a feature not a bug. That's why I ask for constrain.

SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: Really not getting the logic behind your constraints. Why first part should fail and second part should pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with an [indexed view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191432.aspx):

```
create table dbo.T (
    A char(1) not null,
    B char(1) not null
)
go
create view dbo.V_T
with schemabinding
as
    select
        A,
        B,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from
        dbo.T
    group by
        A,B
go
create unique clustered index IX_V_T on dbo.V_T (A)
go
Insert T(A, B) Values('x', 'y')
Insert T(A, B) Values('x', 'y')
Insert T(A, B) Values('x', 'z')
```

The third insert generates the error:

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.V_T' with unique index 'IX_V_T'. The duplicate key value is (x).
The statement has been terminated.
```

And continuing:

```
Insert T(A, B) Values('c', 'y')
Insert T(A, B) Values('d', 'y')
```

Both execute fine.

---

The design of the `V_T` table is such that it has one row for each unique `A,B` combination (the `COUNT_BIG(*)` is just a requirement to allow this to be an indexed view, we're not allowed to use `DISTINCT`). We then simply put a unique index on the `A` values. Therefore, this view can only contain one row for each possible `A` value or the unique constraint will be violated.

Comment: @przemo_li - added some explanation at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSTEAD OF trigger (with fixes based on comments of @Damien_The_Unbeliever):

At first create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    A nchar(1),
    B nchar(1)
);
```

Create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtemp
ON temp
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
INSERT INTO temp
SELECT  A,
        B
FROM (
    SELECT  i.*,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.A ORDER BY i.A,i.B) as DR
    FROM inserted i
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM temp
            WHERE A = i.A
        ) t
    WHERE t.b IS NULL OR t.B = i.B
    ) C
where dr = 1

DELETE t
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON d.A=t.A and d.B=t.B;
```

Then run:

```
Insert temp(A, B) Values
('x','y'),
('x','y'),
('x','z'),
('c','y'),
('d','y'),
('a','b'),
('a','c');
```

Output:

```
A   B
a   b
c   y
d   y
x   y
x   y
```

Comment: Citing my question "Will fail on the second inser as y =/=z.", while Your answer will fail because 'x is not unique'. That's a big difference ;)

Comment: X, y will be inserted x,z will not then. Is it the logic, you requested? I add unique CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Ok. My question was not clear enough. I (x,y)(x,y)(x,z) should only fail at 3rd insert.

Comment: I add trigger solution

Comment: I think your trigger may struggle to operate correctly if faced with a multi-row insert that violates the constraint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I suggest to use trigger without any constraints.

Comment: No, I mean `INSERT INTO temp(A,B) VALUES ('a','b'),('a','c');` will be let through by your trigger. It also claims to be an `instead of` trigger for `update` but actually inserts additional rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am confused with this question... this trigger will actually work ONLY with atomic inserts like `Insert temp(A, B) Values('x', 'y')` and FAIL on insert from your comment.